# Ordered-by-insertion map

Tags: c++, hash-map

The main problem that I tried to tackle here was trying not to have the erase method to be \$O(n)\$. I kept two data structures: a linked-list of pairs and a map of a key and a pair containing a value and a pointer that points to the node in the linked-list.

Am I on the right track? Right now the code is all rough, ugly and all over the place but I tested it and it works properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

template <typename key, typename value>
class table {
    using node = std::pair<key, value>;
    using iterator = typename std::list<std::pair<key, value>>::iterator;
    using value_node = std::pair<value, iterator>;

    std::list<node> list;
    std::map<key, value_node> data;

public:
    table & push(key const & k, value const & v) {
        list.emplace_back(k, v);
        data.emplace(k, value_node {v, std::prev(std::end(list))});
        return *this;
    }

    iterator begin() {
        return std::begin(list);
    }

    iterator end() {
        return std::end(list);
    }

    table & erase(key const & k) {
        list.erase(data[k].second);
        data.erase(k);
        return *this;
    }

    // Just to check if the list items are actually being erased.
    size_t length() const {
        return list.size();
    }

    value & operator [](key const & k) {
        return data[k].first;
    }
};

int main() {

    table<std::string, std::string> t;

    t.push("hello", "world");
    t.push("blabla", "hello");

    cout << t["hello"] << endl;
    cout << t["blabla"] << endl;
    cout << t.length() << endl;

    for (auto const & e : t) {
        cout << e.first << " " << e.second << endl;
    }

    t.erase("hello");
    t.erase("blabla");
    cout << t.length() << endl;

    cout << "Size: " << sizeof(table<int, int>) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason an `unordered_map` wouldn't do the same job?

Comment: The idea is to keep the order of insertion. So when you iterate, you iterate the elements by the order that you've inserted them. Also, one of the challenges was to make the `erase` method fast because of the linked list. The `unordered_map` uses a hash function that randomizes the order of the elements and the `map` sorts them using `<`; none of them keeps the order of insertion.

Comment: If item is not inserted, then `data[k]` is erroneous call, therefore your `erase` function is wrong. You should to use `std::map::at` and get exception or `std::map::find` and compare its result against `std::end(data)`, then in case of failure is is better to return `bool(false)` instead of `*this`.

Comment: You don't need to duplicate neither key nor value at all. 1st option is to use `std::map< std::reference_wrapper< key const >, iterator const, std::less< key > >` instead of your highly expensive way. Another approach is to use `std::set< iterator >` and use your custom comparator. It just adds one level of indirection in `operator []` and others (it is cheap). Also it is better to use `iterator const it = list.insert(std::cend(list), {k, v});` instead of ad-hoc `std::prev(std::end(list))` in both cases. `insert` is more universal way of adding an elements to containers.

Comment: @Orient Thanks, I've changed the code and now it's much much better. (I still haven't updated it here) I am, however, interested in your approach `std::reference_wrapper< key const >, iterator const, std::less< key > >`, could you please explain it a bit better? Are you saying that I should make the map key and value a reference to the first and second element of the list pair? And I'm a still bit confused by your idea of using the set, since my map already has a "reference" to the iterator. `iterator const it = list.insert(std::cend(list), {k, v});` was a nice one ;)

Comment: Idea with `reference_wrapper` is not better, because it still includes duplication of `key`s and `values`. But string "`std::map< std::reference_wrapper< key const >, iterator const, std::less< key > >`" is absolutely enough to understand whole the idea.

Comment: Idea with `std::set` illustrated here: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/4iMnUqFK9YwuJgw7 (it is better to use multiset for your purposes or to add hadling of a cases of equivalent `key`s).

Comment: @Orient Nice, your solution work much better! I understand everything, except the `using is_transparent = void;` what does that line does? Is it important for the comparator?

Comment: Yes. It is important. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317413/what-are-transparent-comparators

Comment: @Orient do I need to put it on that specific line position, or that's irrelevant? Also, do I need to pass the iterator by const? Does it make faster or more secure? Also, on the push method, is there any difference between data.insert vs data.emplace? I tried and they both work.

Comment: You don't need to put it on a specific line position. You don't need pass iterator by const, but pointee of that iterator should be treated as logically const. I.e. immutable in the body of `operator ()` of comparator.

Comment: Also you can pass a key of map/set by non-const reference (if it allowed by STL implementation), but still you should not change the value of the key.

Comment: To pass an iterator by const value is just a way to indicate that its value is not mutable in the function. This practice may be considered as safer one.

Comment: [Here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) you can find a description of `insert` and `emplace` for `std::map`.

Comment: @Orient, I know the superficial differences between them: with `insert` you need to construct the class or structure, while `emplace` calls the constructor directly. However, since here we're just passing a pointer / iterator, there should be no difference between them I believe. I just prefer to use `emplace` because of consistency.

Comment: Using `list.insert(std::cend(list), {k, v});` imply one move of `value_type`.

Comment: I was referring to `data.insert`, data is the `std::set`